# Facebook app to delete friends

Tags: facebook, webapp-rec, friends, facebook-apps

I'm looking for an app that would “measure” how bad friends you are with all your Facebook friends. For example, it could take into account those points:

- If you have friends in common/how many of them.
- If you have common networks/how many of them.
- If there are things that you both like/how many (not too important though).
- How long you have been (Facebook) friends.
- How long each of you have been on Facebook.
- If there are any pictures, comments, etc. that you have tagged together.

Why am I looking for this? I, as many other people, have been using Facebook for a really long time and there's some people that I might have known back in the day good enough as to ask for their Facebook, but don't remember anymore. Also I'm a sociable person, that means I meet a lot of people constantly, some of them become close, some of them don't but my friend list keeps growing. [I think about 200/300 people would be an ideal maximum of Facebook friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_number), at least for me, so I'd love to have an app that, seizing all the points listed (and maybe some more), tells me who I might not really know/remember anymore.

I know you can do a manual search, but an app as the one mentioned would be much easier and faster, so, **do you know any Facebook app that searches for the “worst friends”?** There are hundreds of apps about “best friends,” but I couldn't find any about “worst friends” through Google or Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Wolfram|Alpha Personal Analytics for Facebook**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/facebook/) meets some of the features you are looking for, namely:

> - If you have friends in common/how many of them.
> - If you have common networks/how many of them.

It can list your friends by rank, depending on how many common friends you have with them. It can also show "mutual friend clusters", which are groups of friends connected by a common friend.

It also has a lot of features which show you how you interact with your friends and show that info through a list, chart or graph, and depending on certain factors (e.g. Facebook activity).

[image]

See the [Wolfram|Alpha Personal Analytics for Facebook](http://www.wolframalpha.com/facebook/) page for more info.

---

Also, [Facebook itself has an "**Organize**" tool](https://www.facebook.com/friends/organize) that finds "friends you haven't interacted with lately" at [facebook.com/friends/organize](https://www.facebook.com/friends/organize).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for on the day, but it works (;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a *Worst Friends* app, but perhaps you could look at this from the opposite direction:

1. Make a new Group and add **all** your friends to that group.
2. Using a good *Best Friends* app, find all your best friends and remove them from that group.
3. All the friends remaining in that new group at least not your best friends.
4. Scan the list to see if you can identify some people in the list that you consider good friends and remove them from the group.
5. If you have done a good job selecting your best friends then this list will be a good start (probably not perfect) for your worst friends list.
6. Rather than immediately removing all the people on the list as friends, start by restricting what these friends can see/do.

Perhaps after a time, you can then feel confident to remove them as friends.